# Unable to parse different json format string via GSON

Tags: android, gson

This is not a duplicate question
Please dont mark it as duplicate.
Can this Json be parsed with GSON library?

```
{"keyobject": {"keyarray": ["key1", "key2", "key3"]},
"valueobject": [{"valuearray": ["arr1_val1", "arr1_val2","arr1_val3"]},
{"valuearray": ["arr2_val1", "arr2_val2","arr2_val3"]}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried to parse it using GSON?

Comment: I used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ website to create a POJO class for the above json string but I am not able to map it correctly with my bean class. I am getting two List - one for key array and other for value array.

I dont know how to map each key with the value and I don't want to map it via index of the key as the index might change.

Comment: Why is it that the index will change?

Comment: It might be a case through web service end... Also I think index might not be a best approach to handle json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
class Outer {
  KeyObject keyobject;
  List<ValueObject> valueobject;
}

class KeyObject {
  List<String> keyarray;
}

class ValueObject {
  List<String> valuearray;
}
Outer outer = gson.fromJson(json, Outer.class);
```

Comment: how to handle these two cases with this class - first I only want to parse some of the keys in this json string and secondly if there are large no of keys and if I take first case in consideration I dont think searching key as index is worth.....

Comment: You can define multiple classes with different set of fields. Any extra fields will get ignored during deserialization. Or you can just use JsonParser.parse() method and extract it all in a JsonObject tree, and then operate on it as a DOM.